# Alternative proof of 'a linegraph of a Hamiltonian graph is Hamiltonian'?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

So I've got an assignment to proof that the linegraph of a normal Hamiltonian graph is also Hamiltonian (but not Eulerian most of the time). I've found that this is a direct corollary of a theorem of Harary and Nash-Williams regarding dominating trails.

However, we've never discussed this theorem or dominating trails in class, so I doubt this is the answer they are looking for, so is there an alternative proof? I can't think, however, of any other ways to solve this question.

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ is hamiltonian then we can arrange the vertices of the graph into a cycle. If $G$ has any other edges then they become chords of this cycle. If we want a hamiltonian cycle in $L(G)$, we need to be able to cycle through the edges of $G$ in such a way that consecutive edges in our sequence are incident in the graph. We can do that by moving along the edges of the cycle in $G$, and picking up any chordal edges along the way. See the example below, where the numbers on the edges indicate where they are in our sequence.

[image: Example graph]

This [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-134-03/S0002-9947-1968-0231740-1/S0002-9947-1968-0231740-1.pdf) by Chartrand brings up the concept of *sequential graphs* in determining when a line graph is hamiltonian, which is essentially the technique I presented here.